# Android Hide TimePicker numbers?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Is there a way to hide these numbers? Im guessing there must be an attribute which once set to 'false' should to it.

Also, i've tried to use custom drawables for the the up/down arrow, but those seem to overlay on top of the numbers (ie,the numbers are still visible)

Note: I could make custom pickers where I use a textView in between two imageViews, but the default timePicker allows one to swipe up and scroll through numbers (so would prefer using the default)

Edit: Apparently the NumberPicker has different children in different versions of android(the emulator shows the up/bottom arrows, while on my Samsung Tab they return a nullpointerexception). Wow!

[image: Hide these Numbers]

Comment: u should implement wheel view also as it satisfies your requirement

Comment: see [this](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html)

Comment: @user3355820 I dont want to create a custom picker as in that case the scroll effect wont be possible

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a time picker you could try and use a [number picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) instead, this means that you can specifically set what you want to be in the picker.

Comment: this does not do it .

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to hide these numbers?

No, sorry.

> Im guessing there must be an attribute which once set to 'false' should to it.

Only if you fork `TimePicker` and add such an attribute yourself.

Comment: @alexsummers: I am glad that you like it. The real source of this behavior is `NumberPicker`, where [they hardcode the `SELECTOR_WHEEL_ITEM_COUNT` to 3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java). So, you would need to fork `NumberPicker` to either make that configurable or set it to 1, then fork `TimePicker` to use your revised `NumberPicker`. There might need to be additional changes to `NumberPicker` beyond setting the count to 1, if code elsewhere in the class assumes that there are more wheel items than 1.