# Making a Timepicker smaller

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I want to make invisible the top and the bottom of a Timepicker like the capture below : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kvZy.png

the xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timezd"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Look the screen below, this is the result wanted : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdLZX.png

Edit 1: I use java (I work on Android Studio). And a spinner no, because i want to make invisible the black square in the picture but i wnat to keep the animation slide up and down of the timepicker ;) Ty for ur answer

Comment: what is the purpose of having `timePickerMode` as `spinner` in this case?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve that in pure java android or Xamarin?

Comment: i edit my Question

Comment: Hi @Jalal, this is really queried here before, and it seems that there is no direct solution to your question; you may check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988150/android-hide-timepicker-numbers

Comment: Thank you, i see this post but i was hoping someone have better solution, but seems not. So ty, i will use Numberpicker.